# SQLAlchemy: Selecting with Textual Column Expressions use-cases

Tags: sqlalchemy

Can someone provide me with some use-cases for the ["Selecting with Textual Column Expressions"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#selecting-with-textual-column-expressions) concept of SQLAlchemy?

I fail to see the point behind the given examples in the documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example would be if we wanted to run the query

```sql
SELECT protocol_version FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

against a SQL Server database. `sys.dm_exec_connections` is a system view, not a real table, so this fails:

```py
tbl = sa.Table(
    "dm_exec_connections", sa.MetaData(), schema="sys", autoload_with=engine
)
# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: dm_exec_connections
```

However, this works:

```py
stmt = sa.text("SELECT protocol_version FROM sys.dm_exec_connections")

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt).first()
    print(result.protocol_version)
```